# Do I have to rollBack() before exit()?

Tags: php, pdo

I have code like this

```
try {
  $pdo->beginTransaction();
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query1);
  $stmt->execute($x);
} catch (Exception $e) {
  $pdo->rollBack();
  throw->$e;
}

if (condition) {
  exit();
}

$x['column1'] = 'string1';
$x['column2'] = 'string2';
$x['column3'] = 'string3';

try {
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query2);
  $stmt->execute($x);
  $pdo->commit();
} catch (Exception $e) {
  $pdo->rollBack();
  throw->$e;
}
```

If the `if condition` succeeded and the code did `exit()`

Is everything related to the `$pdo` is safe too or do I add before `exit()` a `$pdo->rollBack();`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically you don't.

PHP will close the database connection on exit.
Database will roll back all active transactions on close.

However, it is quite unlikely that such a case will ever happen in your code because right now it is wrong. You have to wrap **the entire transaction** in a try catch, not just database operations. Otherwise, if an exception will be thrown in your "condition" part, it will break a transaction but won't be caught.

Besides, using exit is a bad practice by itself and amidst a transaction a tenfold.

But if you really really need that (in reality you don't) then do something like

```
try {
  $pdo->beginTransaction();
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query1);
  $stmt->execute($x);

if (condition) {
  throw new Exception("Stopped on condition");
}

$x['column1'] = 'string1';
$x['column2'] = 'string2';
$x['column3'] = 'string3';

  $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query2);
  $stmt->execute($x);
  $pdo->commit();
} catch (Throwable $e) {
  $pdo->rollBack();
  throw->$e;
}
```

Comment: `if there will be exception thrown in your "condition" part, it will break a transaction but won't be caught.` is not that normal because the first `query and transaction start` were a success so no need for the transaction to be caught but the `condition`  stopped everything and giving its own caught error `Stopped on condition` (in my case just `exit()`)?

Comment: Sorry I don't get your question.

Comment: you said `if there will be exception thrown ... it will break a transaction but won't be caught` about the first `try-catch` block - so i am confused because if the block was a success and didn't give an error - then what `it will break a transaction but won't be caught` has to do with `exit()`

Comment: also i want to know how the try-catch block should be like if there was another condition with exit above `$pdo->beginTransaction();` in my original code

Comment: It implied "if there will be exception thrown *between try catch blocks*"

Comment: There should be NO intentional exit amidst a transaction. Period. You are doing something bizarre here. I would advise to ask a new question, "Is it OK to exit during a transaction" and provide a **real life use case** you are working on.  At the moment I have a feeling that you don't really understand what a transaction is and probably misusing it.

Comment: i understand that a transaction is a process that makes sure that all queries and calls of the pdo are executed properly and if they gave error to terminate everything - am i getting it wrong? i have the idea that transaction is only related to database

Comment: yes, you are getting it wrong. You can have all what you said without a transaction. PDO already makes sure  that all queries and calls  are executed properly and if they gave error to terminate everything

Comment: i refactored my code to match what you said but noticed that everytime the condition is true that i get this exception error `Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: There is no active transaction` instead of the intended `Stopped on condition`

Comment: Like I said you just have to remove both  a transaction and a try catch from your code. and you can keep your exit.

Answer (score 2):

From the docs:

> When the script ends or when a connection is about to be closed, if you have an outstanding transaction, PDO will automatically roll it back.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.transactions.php

In my opinion, it's better to run rollback to make sure to other devs that it's not code garbage, someon think about it.